# TabBarController as main view and home page not as a tab

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITabBarController based app. To simplify, let's assume I have one Tab Bar Item pointing to Navigation Controller that holds Table View Controller.

In addition I have a separate Scroll View Controller.

What I'm trying to solve is how can I have Scroll View Controller loaded after app launch and Tab Bar visible at one time. It means that Scroll View shouldn't be one of the tabs.

I'm puzzled how to achieve it. Appreciated for any help.

Comment: i didn't get the question..you can show just 1 controller at 1 time.

Comment: You can have the tab bar controller be the root view controller of the window, but present the scroll view controller modally (with no animation) from the controller in the first tab. You should present it from the viewDidAppear method, and if you do that with no animation, it should be the first thing the user sees.

Comment: you can set a `UINavigationController` as `rootViewController` and push the `UITabBarController` into that stack, then if you need to show e.g. your `UIViewController` with the `UIScollView` from the `UITabViewController` just push it into the original stack as usually you'd do. why is that solution not good enough for you?